# Error adding WrapPanel

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, wrappanel

I created a new blank Windows 10 Universal app and tried to add a `WrapPanel` exactly as per the sample code in the link: [WrapPanel XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel)

I am getting the following error message on `wrapPanel:WrapPanel`

> The name "WrapPanel" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.WrapPanel"

I have already added `xmlns:wrapPanel="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.WrapPanel"` as per sample code.

Full code and errors (please click image for better quality):

[image: WrapPanel full code and errors]

I have tried to Clean and Build/Rebuild but it doesn't help. I also made sure that I am targeting the latest Windows 10 version:

[image: WrapPanel Target Windows version]

Please help!

**Update**: I tried using `xmlns:wrapPanel="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`
 as suggested but I still get this error. Again, I tried clean and build/rebuild and am getting the a similar error:

[image: WrapPanel Error update]

Comment: You can download the sample app [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq). 
It has live examples which will always work, the code for the wrappanel one is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.bind).

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT using the code on github, I am still getting a similar error. please see updated screenshot on the question. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has a typo. The `WrapPanel` control is not in the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.WrapPanel` namespace, but rather just in `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`, so use the following

```
xmlns:wrapPanel="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

And it should work as expected. I will push an update for the docs.

Comment: I am still getting a similar error when i point to `xmlns:wrapPanel="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"` instead as suggested. Please see updated screenshot on the question

Comment: Have you installed the UWP Community Toolkit (Controls) package from NuGet? Could you post a screenshot of references section in the project expanded?